# Codeigniter Php.ini File Location on Shared Server to increase file upload limit

Tags: php, codeigniter, path, continuous-integration, location

Problem: **where to upload php.ini file in codeigniter to increase the file upload size**

**At wordpress i have tried in wp-admin folder and it worked.**

but in codeigniter i don't know **where to upload php.ini** to fix it, right now its processing upto 100% but video file is not uploading in CI. upto 2MB file is uploading but more than that its not working

i am using this code in php.ini

**upload_max_filesize = 2500M
post_max_size = 250M**

Comment: Normally this is not configurable on a shared server, but you can try setting this parameter from PHP code maybe that will work for you

Comment: Oh and `post_max_size` needs to be > `upload_max_filesize` as the files ride along with other posted fields

Comment: depending on your shared server, you might be able to upload that size via ftp